# modal can't access its show function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
$('#modalSetDonationsProducts').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert("dljasld");
    rowNumber = 1;
    $('#tblEmployees tbody tr').remove("tr:gt(0)");
    alert("enterd");
    var itemname = $(this).parent().parent().find(rowData["ItemName"]).val()
    alert(itemname);              
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="item"]').val(itemName);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="description"]').val(itemName);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="item"]').enabled = false;      
});
```

I have this function 
and modal

```
<div class="modal modal-flex " id="modalSetDonationsProducts">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="min-width: 900px; max-width:1000px;width:auto">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="width:100%;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">&nbsp;<%= GetLocalResourceObject("addnewitem")%></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p><%= GetLocalResourceObject("addnewitem")%></p>

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table" id="tblEmployees">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="rowID1">
                                <td>1</td>                                     
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" style="min-width:230px" readonly="readonly" name="item" value="" /></td>   </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div> </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                <button type="button" onclick="SaveProducts();" class="btn btn-green ladda-button">                           
                </button>                       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call modal by this

```
<a data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#modalSetDonationsProducts\"   class=\"btn btn-green\" name=\"btnSplit\">add</a>
```

What Already done is :

```
 1. model open Correctly .      

 2. it can't access the $('#modalSetDonationsProducts').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) and    show the first alert at least .

 3. my modal call by button from another table and I just want to set the input name="item" by parent.find way.
```

Comment: it seems like, you have missed, `;` semi-colon (`alert("dljasld")`), because of which it is proceeding further to execute your onShowOfModal Event.

Comment: I think it has no effect, or do you mean another

Comment: You should not escape title and href if that's how your html looks.

Comment: <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modalSetDonationsProducts">click to show modal</a> - no escaping

Comment: @PoulBak Nothing Changed :( , modal opened but alert didn't fired

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3rfb4vny/

i guess you are going wrong with your targeting elements, i have tried your HTML and JS event

```
$('#modalSetDonationsProducts').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert("displaying");
});
```

Comment: `<a title=\"split to more than one product\" href=\"#modalSetDonationsProducts\"  data-toggle=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-green\" name=\"btnSplit\">Add</a>` I call modal by this Tag , is there any notice ?  @ameenulla0007

Comment: I call this tag dynamically in Jquery, So I can't remove this slashes

Comment: Oh.. You would have mentioned this in your question clearly. Actually, data toggle attributes are targeted when it is ready HTML.

Comment: @saraadly, will be clear with your function, where you have called the modal calling button? as well as, try the `$('#modalSetDonationsProducts').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {` without any other statements, just try an alert there, and let me know what's the impact?